# MSBuild web deploy to IIS express

Tags: iis, msbuild, teamcity, iis-express, webdeploy

Is it possible to publish website using MSBuild to IIS express?  I need to specify user credentionals as login and password but cant find how can I setup user account on IIS.

In whole how can I veryfie that localhost:8172/MsDeploy.axd service is working (if it can be used for express version)? Thanks.

P.S

I am using teamcity with MSBuild for publish and here are my command line params for MSBuild:

```
    /P:Configuration=%environment-name%
    /P:DeployOnBuild=True
    /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
    /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://%destination-server%:8172/MsDeploy.axd
    /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
    /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
    /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
    /P:UserName=%destination-server-user%
    /P:Password=%destination-server-password%
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=”Default Web Site/myapp-%environment-name%”
```

Comment: Just curious: why are you using IIS express on the target machine instead of normal IIS installation? And how do you ensure it is started and running?

Comment: A much simpler method would be to publish to the folder that IIS Express is pointing to. Getting msdeploy publish to work with IIS Express will not be easy (nor supported).